# Strange Behavior...Only some text cannot be drawn with reporlab in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

I wanted to have certain space inbetween each string so I made a function like below and drew string.

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape

bytes = BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(bytes, pagesize=landscape(A4))

def map_each(text,x,y,w):
    for moji in text:
        c.drawString((x+w*text.index(moji))*mm,y*mm,str(moji))

fontname="Times-Roman"
p2="299"
p4="1950"
cha="261"
classification="抹"
               
c.setFont(fontname,12)
# c.drawString(58*mm,160*mm,p2)
map_each(p2, 58, 160, 6)
map_each(p4, 94, 160, 6)
map_each(cha, 124, 160, 6)
if classification=="抹":
    syubetsu="11"
elif classification=="車":
    syubetsu=" 3"
map_each(syubetsu,43,190,7)

c.save()

with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytes.getbuffer())
```

And then I get this.

["1 1" is "1 " and "2 9 9" is "2 9  " while "1 9 5 0" or "2 6 1" are "1 9 5 0" and "2 6 1" just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2kRT.png)

If I just use drawString like the one I commented out or print each letter in a loop to make sure,
"1 1" and "2 9 9" are there there.

Is it possible that reportlab sometimes cannot draw strings too close to the next?
Only sometimes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text.index` returns the first occurrence in the string, try this instead:

```py
for index, moji in enumerate(text):
    c.drawString((x+w*index)*mm, y*mm, moji)
```

Comment: Oh yes because I used list.index() and it was "11" and "99"!
Thank you for this and adding all what I didn't write.

Comment: @Kantumrobot I think in this case it's `str.index`, not `list.index`.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment. Exactly. Again, thank you for your help.